# Joint Reports of Multiple Objects

Tags: fields, object, rforcecom

I am using the RForcecom library of R to download fields of different objects. I am trying to access a standard field (call it `AccountID`) of one object (Account), which is also read by other object (Opportunity), and connects these two objects as a unique identifier.

It is that each client has an account (parent object), and after some conditions are met, an Opportunity (child object) is created for them. Therefore, Opportunity also has `AccountID`, but it is not its own field.

I am using the `rforcecom.retrieve(session, object, fields)` command, which does not allow me to access `AccountID` of Opportunity object.

Is there any other command that I could use to retrieve fields from joint objects?